# How to highlight and list missing values in a letter-number sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm using Excel 2010. I have a column of data that contains four-digit sequences. These sequences consist of and iterate through a number of the alphabet followed by a number from 100-999. So A100, A101, A102... A999, then B100, B101... all the way up until Z999. There are 24,000 of these sequences (i.e. rows).

I first tried the following VBA script:

```vb
Function MissingNumbers(Rng As Range) As String
Dim X As Long, MaxNum As Long
MaxNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
ReDim Nums(1 To MaxNum)
For X = 1 To MaxNum
   If Rng.Find(X, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
      MissingNumbers = MissingNumbers & ", " & X
   End If
  Next
  MissingNumbers = Mid(MissingNumbers, 3)
End Function
```

...but I ran into an error when calling it with `=MissingNumbers(A1:A23400)`, which I'm guessing is because the function can't parse the alphabetic letters at the beginning of the sequences.

**My question: what formula can I use to *both highlight and separately list* missing values in my first column?**

For extra clarification, missing values in the range

```
C996
C998
C999
D101
```

...would be...

```
C996
*C997*
C998
C999
*D100*
D101
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's perhaps more speedy way to do this ... but this is tested and produced results on a small sample.

```
Function MissingSequence(Rng As Range) As String

Dim iCnt As Integer
For iCnt = 65 To 90 'ASCI characters for alphabet A-Z

    Dim iNum As Integer
    For iNum = 100 To 999

        Dim sCheck As String
        sCheck = Chr(iCnt) & iNum            

        If Rng.Find(sCheck, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

            Dim sMissingNumbers As String
            sMissingNumbers = sMissingNumbers & "," & sCheck

        End If

    Next

Next

  MissingSequence = Mid(sMissingNumbers, 2)

End Function
```

Comment: How would I call this? Sorry, today was the first time I used Excel, picking it up as I go along. :-)

Comment: Okay, I tried calling it with `=MissingSequence(A1:A23400)` the first time, which failed with an error. Then I added `Public` before `Function`, and that seemed to do the trick - something was definitely running while minimising and maximising the window, and it did that for about 20-30 seconds. I'd really appreciate some sort of confirmation that it ran successfully, especially since I'm unsure whether this dataset has any missing numbers in it.

Comment: @Hashim - for confirmation use a `debug.print MissingSequence` to print results to the Immediate Window in the VBE. Also, make sure you pass an actual range `A1:A23400` is a string literal. I think you will need `Range(A1:A23400)`.

Comment: Do you mean use a `debug.print` when calling the function? Also, what would using the Range look like in code? Where would I place it?

Comment: @Hashim - `sMyString = MissingSequence(Range("A1:A23400"))`.. then debug.print `sMyString`. Place this is a separate procedure then run.